# Create new object from existent object in DB using Symfony2 and Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I need to create a new set of DB records by using same data that already exists. See image below:

[image]

Using this as example I need to create the same set of records but just changing the column company, less take `UPC = I5TYF1UPORMYUY4JT21Z`, using this info I should be able to generate two rows by just changing the company to `52` (any number). What I think is to get those records using this:

```
$entityStockDetailHasProductDetail = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('ProductBundle:StockDetailHasProductDetail')->findBy(array(
    "product" => $request->request->get('product')['id'],
    "upc" => $request->request->get('product')['upc'],
));
```

Which returns the right records but I don't know how to continue from that point. My entity has all this methods:

```
$entityStockDetailHasProductDetail->setProductDetail();
$entityStockDetailHasProductDetail->setUpc();
$entityStockDetailHasProductDetail->setProduct();
$entityStockDetailHasProductDetail->setCompany();
$entityStockDetailHasProductDetail->setCondition();
$entityStockDetailHasProductDetail->setContent();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over the collection, **clone** your entities, set the new company and persist.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('default');
$collection = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Entity')->findBy(array('...'));

foreach ($collection as $entity) {
    $newEntity = clone $entity;
    $newEntity
       ->setId(null)
       ->setCompany($company)
    ;
    $em->persist($newEntity);
}
$em->flush();
```